# Split a string at 2 points

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a file called **file_test1.txt** and I want to extract just **test1** from the name and place it in a string. Whats the best way of doing this?

E.g.

```
string fullfile = @"C:\file_test1.txt";
string section = [test1] from fullfile;      // <- expected result
```

I want to be able to split on **'file_'** and **'.txt'** as the **'test1'** section could be larger or smaller however the **'file_'** and **'.txt'** will always be the same.

Comment: *will always* is **never** true. :)

Comment: Seems true enough when you are parsing files you generate in another utility, only files you generate in that utility, and do not want to find any other potential matches, and control the templating of that utility's filename generation.

Comment: I agree with IAbstract, Assumption is the mother of all... What should happen when the file is called `file_test1.txt.txt`? I would still go wit a more dynamic approach, just to be as sure as possible.

Comment: well, I believe the result for your proposal should be `test1.txt`, Silvermind, but i'd need to kick it back to the analyst for spec confirmation on that....

Comment: I am creating the files in another program and they are stored in a controlled folder, that is why i can say they _will always be the same._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullfile).Substring(5)` (or `Substring("TEMPLATE_PREFIX".Length)`)

Comment: I would actually recommend a combination of this solution and the `Split` solution by @Satpal. This would allow a much greater range of flexibility in changing file name formats; therefore as long as you can split on `'_'` then you can have any length of characters preceding the underscore.

Comment: Using substring lets you have your split-target show up in the text you wanted to extract without 'oops' cases like @AdiLester pointed out.

Comment: used just the following; `string fullfile = @"C:\file_test1.txt";
string section = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullfile).Substring(5)`  This is best for my needs as **section** could be **test-1** or **test-1-3-4** so i only need to _trim_ bits off.

Answer (score 2):

You can try spilt

```
 var test = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullfile).split('_')[1];
```

Comment: no but the syntax of the files that this will be run on is 'file_[bit i want].txt'. The files are created by another application i have created.

Comment: If you know in advance that you won't have any other underscores then this will do. I've added a similar answer that also knows how to handle multiple underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
string fullfile = @"C:\file_test1.txt";
var name = fullfile.Substring(8,fullfile.Length-12)
```

As c:\file_ and .txt are fixed, You can take Substring starting at index 8 (skip leading name), upto length of total string length - 12 (12 => length of leading name, and trailing extension)

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd give a solution that uses `Split` and handles files with multiple underscores:

```
string.Join("_", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Split('_').Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

String.Split() works quite well for my uses:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Obviously many ways to accomplish this.  Here's yet another approach:

```
        string fullfile = @"C:\file_test1.txt";
        int index1 = fullfile.LastIndexOf("file_");
        if (index1 != -1)
        {
            int index2 = fullfile.IndexOf(".", index1);
            if (index2 != -1)
            {
                string section = fullfile.Substring(index1 + 5, index2 - index1 - 5);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for the options, the other one is a little shorter and works as required.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get "test1", or any subsequent filename (assuming your file naming convention remains constant!) using this regular expression:

```
var defaultRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=_).*(?=.txt)");

var matches = defaultRegex.Matches(fullfile);

var match = matches[0].Value;
```

The regular expression:

> (?<=_).*(?=.txt)

uses positive look behind to find text preceded by '_', and also positive lookahead to find text which has '.txt' ahead of it.